# Problem with beamer package!

Tags: beamer

When i compile my beamer file with bibtex, it gives the following error :

! LaTeX Error: File `stmaryrd.sty' not found.Type X to quit or  to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop. \usepackage

i am using the following preamble:

```
\documentclass[french,12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{texdraw}
\usepackage{xy}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsopn}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{beamerthemeWarsaw} 
%\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\usetheme{AnnArbor}  % %   
%\usetheme{EastLansing}
%\usetheme{Antibes}
%\usetheme{PaloAlto} % les deux cotÃ©
%\usecolortheme{seagull}  % Les couleurs sans commentaire
\usefonttheme{serif}   %les polices sans commentaire
%\useinnertheme{circle}  %innertheme ThÃ¨me pour l'intÃ©rieur de la diapositive :liste, block, tableau etc 
\useoutertheme{shadow}  %outertheme Theme pour l'extÃ©rieur de la diapositive :Titre de la diapositive, entete, pied de page
%\usetheme{PaloAlto}
%\usetheme{Malmoe}
%\usecolortheme[named=green]{structure}

\title{\textbf{....}}
\author{LABENI Hicham}
\date{02/11/2018}
\institute{\textbf{UCP}}
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Plan}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Well, this means that `stmaryrd.sty` cannot be found on the standard search paths. The solution probably is to install this package. How, depends on the TeX distirbution that you use.

Comment: @gernot can you explain how to install it please, i tried and it didn't work !!

Comment: As I wrote: How installation works depends on which TeX distribution on which platform you are using. MiKTeX or TeXLive on Windows? TeXLive on Linux/Unix?

Comment: @gernot i am using Miktex!

Comment: Not related to the problem, but only load packages that you *need*, and don't load packages more than once. Don't load `epsfig` at all; it has been deprecated for more than 1/4 century.

Comment: @BriganosBriganos: For MiKTeX there is a MiKTeX Package Manager (MPM) installed. Try that.

Comment: there isn't `\end{document}`

Comment: I do not use MiKTeX myself, but maybe this [Howto](https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console) helps. There are also videos on YouTube, like [one from the university of Akron](https://youtu.be/_6GdlfLC1lY).